# LINQ only select data after current time for today

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having problems with a LINQ query - im using it to select some flight time data :

```
new XElement("Data",

                  from data in table
                  select new XElement("data", new XAttribute("data","data"),
                         new XElement("scheduledGateTime", data[1]),
                         new XElement("destinationCity", data[2]),
                         new XElement("flightNumber", data[3]),
                         new XElement("status", data[4]),
                         new XElement("terminal", data[4])

                         )
              )
```

Im having problems with filtering, at the moment that brings all the data, but i need it to only select when the "scheduledGateTime" is after the current time for today.

For example, if the gate time is 09:05, and it is currently 13:10, i dont want this to be selected.. but if the game time is 13:11, it should be selected.

Ive not used LINQ much and cant figure out how to do this, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What is `table` here? A list, Datatable ?

Comment: its a list    :    List<List<string>> table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
new XElement("Data",
              from data in table
              where DateTime.ParseExact(data[1], "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) > DateTime.Now
              select new XElement("data", new XAttribute("data","data"),
                     new XElement("scheduledGateTime", data[1]),
                     new XElement("destinationCity", data[2]),
                     new XElement("flightNumber", data[3]),
                     new XElement("status", data[4]),
                     new XElement("terminal", data[4])
                     )
```

You may need to fiddle with the `DateTime` format, I've assumed "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss".

Comment: Worked perfectly, for what i was doing changed the format to "HH:mm". Thanks mate